# Installing python2.4 virtualenv on windows 8 with python2.7 - error base64.py

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I have a problem with a Python2.4 virtualenv install on my python2.7 windows.

I created a virtualenv for my python2.7 programms and want to build virtualenv for my python2.4 program

SO i first DL and install python2.4 on my windows8 with no problem... folder c:/Python24 ( python 2.7 is on c:/Python27 )

On en shell

```
 D:\xxx\projet_django>virtualenv --python=c:/Python24/python.exe env_python2
.4
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:/Python24/python.exe
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 10, in ?
    import base64
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\base64.py", line 346
    with open(args[0], 'rb') as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So i try

```
C:\>cd Python24

C:\Python24>python
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Python 2.4.3 (#69, Mar 29 2006, 17:35:34) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import base64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\base64.py", line 346
    with open(args[0], 'rb') as f:
            ^
```

SO the problem is base64.py use the WITH fonction doesn't exist on python2.4 ... so why my python2.7 virtualenv try to use python2.4 to install my virtualenv ?

And what can i do now ?
thx
laurent

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Python 2.4 is badly installed: when you start it, it shouldn't try to read the files from `C:\Python27\Lib\`.  I can't tell more where the problem is, but you should be able to figure it out, if necessary by reinstalling Python 2.4 from scratch from the official installer.

**EDIT:** also, look out for the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  Maybe it is pointing to `C:\Python27`.  That's a bad idea :-)